# PHPMailer timeout on AWS Linux server

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmailer

I have PHPMailer on an AWS EC2 Linux server and can't send mail using IsSMTP (I need this protocol). My PHPMailer error report is as follows:

```
2017-04-21 18:41:15 Connection: opening to just60.justhost.com:465, timeout=300, options=array ()
2017-04-21 18:41:15 Connection: opened
2017-04-21 18:46:15 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2017-04-21 18:46:15 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  ""
2017-04-21 18:46:15 SMTP -> get_lines(): timed-out (300 sec)
2017-04-21 18:46:15 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2017-04-21 18:46:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mydomain.com
2017-04-21 18:46:15 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2017-04-21 18:46:15 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  ""
2017-04-21 18:46:15 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2017-04-21 18:46:15 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed:
2017-04-21 18:46:15 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
2017-04-21 18:46:15 Connection: closed
2017-04-21 18:46:15 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2017-04-21 18:46:15 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

{"error":"Email error: SMTP connect() failed. https:\/\/github.com\/PHPMailer\/PHPMailer\/wiki\/Troubleshooting"
}
```

All works fine using other protocols (IsSendmail & IsMail), but not IsSMTP, which for some reason times out.

All outgoing ports are open, Postfix and SELinux are installed (SELinux has no enforcing enabled).  It seems it always times out after 5 mins, so either the "open connection" data is not getting out, or the data is not getting back in, but why?

I have tried running it from a secure https site using a gmail account with the following error:

```
2017-04-22 17:00:40 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array (
                                      )
2017-04-22 17:00:40 Connection: opened
2017-04-22 17:00:50 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2017-04-22 17:00:50 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  ""
2017-04-22 17:00:50 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2017-04-22 17:00:50 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
2017-04-22 17:00:50 Connection: closed
2017-04-22 17:00:50 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2017-04-22 17:00:50 SMTP connect() failed.
```

Comment: It looks like your mail credntials are incorrect.

Comment: It's not actually getting as far as trying to log in. I suspect that AWS blocks outbound SMTP by default. You can easily test it using the commands shown in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide, so do that before trying to deal with PHP-level stuff.

Comment: I have done some more testing.
The server is not HTTPS (there is a good reason why)
Hangs for 5 mins when TLS/SSL
Non secure, some SMTP servers are ok, others give error "We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited"

Seems the hanging is due to TLS/SSL

Comment: I have tried running it from an https site, same problem

Answer (score -1):

You might be in sandbox mode if this is the first time you're setting up SES on this AWS account.

These restrictions apply:

- You can only send mail to the Amazon SES mailbox simulator and to verified email addresses and domains
- You can only send mail from verified email addresses and domains
- You can send a maximum of 200 messages per 24-hour period
- Amazon SES can accept a maximum of one message from your account per second

[AWS SES Sandbox](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html)

You'll need to submit a support ticket in AWS to get out of the sandbox.